# Measure Theory and $L^{p}$ spaces

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I have the two following very simple questions regarding measure theory that I want to show:

1. If $f \in L^{p}(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$, then $f < \infty$ $\mu$-almost everywhere (or, $f < \infty$ for all $x \in X$ except for a $\mu$-null set $E \in \mathcal{M}$).
2. If $f=0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere (for a measure space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$), then $\int f \mathrm{d\mu}=0$

---

1. For this, I'm not so sure on how to begin. If $p=\infty$, the result is trivial by the definition of the essential supremum. However, for the other case I don't know how to approach it.
2. The converse is straightforward and it follows by Tchebyshev's inequality, but I don't know where to begin in order to prove the converse statement.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let $E_n=\{x:|f|>n, \:n\in \Bbb{N}\}$. Then by Chebyshev's inequality
   $$
   \mu(E_n)\leqslant \frac1{n^p}\int_{X}|f|^pd\mu\quad\text{and }\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(E_n)=0
   $$
   Let $E=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$. Then $E=\{x:|f|=\infty\}$. Since $E_1\supset\cdots\supset E_n\supset\cdots\supset E$, by Monotone class theorem
   $$
   \mu(E)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(E_n)=0
   $$
   So $\mu(\{x:|f|<\infty\})=\mu(E^c)$, i.e. $|f|<\infty$ a.e.
2. Let $A=\{x:|f|\ne 0\}$. Then $\mu(A)=0$. For any $C\subset X$, $\mu(C\cap A)=0$. So
   $$
   \int_{C}|f|^pd\mu=\int_{C\cap A}|f|^pd\mu+\int_{C\cap A^c}|f|^pd\mu=0
   $$

Comment: Why would $\int_{C \cap A}|f|^{p}d\mu=0$ if $\mu(C \cap A)=0$? I'm guessing we have to assume that $f$ is integrable? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: $\int_{C\cap A}|f|^pd\mu=\sup{\sum_{n\ge 1}a_{n}\mu(E_n)}=0$, where $\bigcup E_n=C\cap A$ and so $\mu(E_n)=0$

Comment: I don't really get why the integral is equal to the supremum of the sum you just showed. Or do you mean the supremum over the integrals of the simple functions? (by the definition of the integral of $|f|$). Why would $\bigcup E_{n} = C \cap A$? I see why $f$ isn't necessarily integrable.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Sorry for being so clueless.

Answer (score 1):

1. If $f=\infty$ on a set of positive measure, say $E$, then

$$\int |f|^p \ge \int |f|^p 1_E =\infty.$$

2. $|\int f|\le \int|f| =0$ because $|f|=0$ $\mu$-a.e. and for $g\in L^+$ this can be shown using the definition of the integral (i.e., $\sup\{\int \phi : \phi \text{ is simple s.t. }0\le\phi\le g\}$).

   Also the converse is not true in general (only for nonnegative functions).